# How to render bootstrap grid from array with map in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

After fetching data from the backend. I want to render data in bootstrap grid but in reactjs if you open an element for example () you cannot wait until 3 occurences to close the div. 
This is a code sample about my problem

```
export default class Posts extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({ posts: json })
            })
    }

    renderPosts() {
        const { posts } = this.state;

        if (posts.length > 0) {

            posts.map((post, index) => {

                // This is my issue here

                if (index === 0) {

                    return (<div className="row">

                        <div> className="col-sm">{post.title} </div>)

                } else if (index % 5 === 0) {


                    return (</div className="row">
                        <div className="row">
                        <div> className="col-sm">{post.title} </div>)

                } else {
                    return (<div> className="col-sm">{post.title} </div>)
                }

            })

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderPosts()}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem more or can you create a codesandbox for this ?

Comment: My problem is mapping and rendering the grid I can't open <div className="row"> and wait until the columns is rendered then close the div.I solved the problem by grouping all my data in array that represents rows. and inside this array is arrays that contains the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by grouping my data into an array of arrays. The array represents the rows. and inside of it arrays that represents the columns.

```
const RowPostGroups = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i = i + 5)
                RowPostGroups.push(photos.slice(i, i + 5));
// then map for rows
// then map for columns
```